# Compare query value with a static list

Tags: grafana, influxdb

I am new to grafana/influxdb and using sql like queries in grafana with data source influxdb. I have a distinct list of states from a select query. I want to compare the states with a static comma separated list (pre defined template variable) of state names and want to identify the missing states.

I tried the query and something like below
`where state_name!~/TX/AZ/ND/`
This works but if the select query is not having a state say TX then i am not able to identify that. But say the select query has MN then that gets listed in the table visualization. So basically i want to find any difference in the state names so that I can identify the missing ones. Looking for help/guidance from the grafana influxdb experts.